# Vectorizing numpy multidimensional array. Operation array wise not element wise

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I wasn't able to find some answer here, so I hope you guys can help.
We all know, that we shouldn't iterate over an Array in python because it take so much time, so I want to vectorize it.
First the Operation:
My operation shall compare two 1D distributions:

```
from pyemd import emd
def vectoriztaion(a=np.ones(25),b=np.ones(25)):
    value = pyemd.emd(np.array(a), np.array(b), helper.get_distance_matrix())
    return value
```

As you can see the input a and b are np.arrays of shape(25).
Now I planned to use the np.vectorize function

```
vfunc = np.vectorize(vectoriztaion)
result = vfunc(A,B)
```

where A and B are Both an np.array of shape(N,25).
I want the code to return an np.array of shape(N).

Running the Code giive me this Error:

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)
```

If you have seen a similar question or if you know how I can get the Code running. 
Pls, let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: no.vectorize doesn't help with speed.  Read the whole docs!

Comment: You are right. My premise was wrong regarding that it is faster than a for loop.
Still My question remain if there is a best approach regarding my problem.

Comment: What’s wrong with just calling `pyemd.emd()` directly?

Comment: pyemd.emd take on two 1D array, but I have all the 1D arrays in a bigger array.
A = [1Darray_a1,1Darray_a2]
B = [1Darray_b1,1Darray_b2]

and I want at the end
-> vfunc(A,B) resulting in -> [pyemd.emd(1Darray_a1,1Darray_b1) , pyemd.emd(1Darray_a2,1Darray_b2)]

I could do it in a for loop, but I would like to know what the best approach is.